# How to stream large data from database via REST in Quarkus

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jax-rs, quarkus

I'm implementing a `GET` method in Quarkus that should send large amounts of data to the client. The data is read from the database using JPA/Hibernate, serialized to JSON, and then sent to the client. How can this can be done efficiently without having the whole data in memory? I tried the following three possibilities all without success:

1. Use `getResultList` from JPA and return a `Response` with the list as the body. A `MessageBodyWriter` will take care of serializing the list to JSON. However, this will pull all data into memory which is not feasible for a larger number of records.
2. Use `getResultStream` from JPA and return a `Response` with the stream as the body. A `MessageBodyWriter` will take care of serializing the stream to JSON. Unfortunately this doesn't work because it seems the `EntityManager` is closed after the JAX-RS method has been executed and before the `MessageBodyWriter` is invoked. This means that the underlying `ResultSet` is also closed and the writer cannot read from the stream any more.
3. Use a `StreamingOutput` as `Response` body. The same problem as in 2. occurs.

So my question is: what's the trick for sending large data read via JPA with Quarkus?

Comment: a standard approach to read chunks of larger amounts of data would be pagination, how does your use-case look like so that this is not feasable?

Comment: I want to avoid paging because if streaming results works there is no need for paging.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have some resources that can help you with this:

- Using reactive Hibernate: https://quarkusio.zulipchat.com/#narrow/stream/187030-users/topic/Large.20datasets.20using.20reactive.20SQL.20clients
- Paging vs Forward only ResultSets: https://knes1.github.io/blog/2015/2015-10-19-streaming-mysql-results-using-java8-streams-and-spring-data.html

The last article is for SpringBoot, but the idea can also be implemented with Quarkus.

------------Edit:

OK, I've worked out an example where I do a batch select. I did it with Panache, but you can do it easily also without it.

I'm returning a ScrollableResult, then use this in the Rest resource to stream it via SSE (server sent event) to the client.

------------Edit 2:

I've added the setFetchSize to the query. You should play with this number and set it between 1-50. If value = 1, then the db rows will be fetched 1 by 1, this mimics streaming the most. And it will use the least amount of memory, but the I/O between the db & app will be more often.

And the usage of a StatelessSession is highly recommended when doing bulk operations like this.

```
@Entity
public class Fruit extends PanacheEntity {

    public String name;
    
    // I've removed the logic from here to the Rest resource, 
     // otherwise you cannot close the session
    
}
```

```
@Path("/fruits")
public class FruitResource {

    @GET
    @Produces(SERVER_SENT_EVENTS)
    public void fruitsStream(@Context Sse sse, @Context SseEventSink sink) {
        var sf = Fruit.getEntityManager().getEntityManagerFactory().unwrap(SessionFactory.class);

        try (var session = sf.openStatelessSession();
             var scrollableResults = session.createQuery("select f from Fruit f")
                                    .scroll(ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY) 
                                    .setFetchSize(1) {
            while (scrollableResults.next()) {
                sink.send(sse.newEventBuilder().data(scrollableResults.get(0)).mediaType(APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).build());
            }
            sink.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Then I call this Rest endpoint like this (via httpie):

```
> http :8080/fruits --stream

data: {"id":9996,"name":"applecfcdd592-1934-4f0e-a6a8-2f88fae5d14c"}

data: {"id":9997,"name":"apple7f5045a8-03bd-4bf5-9809-03b22069d9f3"}

data: {"id":9998,"name":"apple0982b65a-bc74-408f-a6e7-a165ec3250a1"}

data: {"id":9999,"name":"apple2f347c25-d0a1-46b7-bcb6-1f1fd5098402"}

data: {"id":10000,"name":"apple65d456b8-fb04-41da-bf07-73c962930629"}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I'm not sure if this will help. For reactive SQL https://quarkus.io/guides/reactive-sql-clients states that "When the operation completes, we will get a RowSet that has all the rows buffered in memory." But I do *not* want all rows be buffered in memory. And returning a Stream from a JAX-RS method doesn't work as I already explained in my question.

Comment: No, you should definitely not load all the rows in memory. The idea is to process the rows 1 by 1, that's the fastest way and it also consumes the least memory. Check the 2nd article, and see how they have applied forward only resultsets.

Have you tried something like this (I assume you are using Panache):

`
return findAll()
                .withHint(QueryHints.HINT_FETCH_SIZE, Integer.MIN_VALUE)
                .withHint(QueryHints.HINT_FLUSH_MODE, FlushMode.MANUAL)
                .withHint(QueryHints.HINT_READONLY, true)
                .stream();
`

Comment: We do not use Panache. But as I said before a stream on a result set is not valid any more once the JAX-RS MessageBodyWriter is invoked. Therefore you cannot return a stream from the GET method. The article you mentioned writes into the ServletOutputStream directly but since Quarkus doesn't use servlets this is not possible. Also it will bypass any JAX-RS providers. Therefore this is not an option.

Comment: Unfortunately the first link is gated by a Zulip login prompt

Answer (score 0):

Do your results have to be all in one response? How about making the client request the next results page until there's no next - a typical REST API pagination exercise? Also the JPA backend will only fetch that page from the database so there's no moment when everything would sit in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirement you have two options:

Option 1:
Take HATEOAS approach (https://restfulapi.net/hateoas/). One of standard pattern to exchange large data sets over REST standard. So in this approach server will respond with set of HATEOAS URIs in first response quickly. Where each HATEOAS URI represents on group of elements. So you need to generate these URIs based on data size and let client code to take responsibility of calling these URIs individually as REST APIs to get actual data. But again in this option also you can consider Reactive style to get more advantage of streaming processing with small memory foot print.

Option 2:
As suggested by @Serkan above, continuously stream the result set from database as REST response to client. Here you need to make sure the gateway between client and Service for timeout settings. If there is no gateway you are good. So you can take advantage of reactive programming at all layers to achieve continuous streaming. "DAO/data access layer" --> "Service layer" --> REST Controller --> Client. Spring reactor is compliant of JAX-RS as well. https://quarkus.io/guides/getting-started-reactive. This is best architecture style while dealing large data processing.